# Esséen concentration inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, inequality

I want to prove the following:

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then for any $r>0, \epsilon >0$:

$\displaystyle \sup_{x_{0}\in \mathbb{R}^d}{\bf{P}}(|X-x_{0}|\leq r)\leq C_{d,\epsilon} r^d\displaystyle\int_{t\in\mathbb{R}^d:|t|\leq\epsilon /r} |F_{X}(t)|dt $

for some constant $C_{d,\epsilon}$ depending only on $d$ and $\epsilon$. $F_{X}$ is here the charateristic function of $X$.

The hint says to use the formula ${\bf{E}}\phi(X)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\widehat{\phi} (t)F_{X}(t)dt$ for some Schwartz function $\phi$.I have tried for some indicator function (as a limit of Schwartz functions), but never get the $r^d$ on the RHS.

Comment: It is actually exercice 2.2.11 in T. Tao's Random matrix theory book.

Comment: The constant $r$ can be absorbed by a substitution on the integral defining the RHS. Hence it's enough to do it for $r=1$ (consider $X/r$ instead of $X$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is proved in T. Tao's book *Additive combinatorics* ([Lemma 7.17.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=xpimQMtn5-IC&pg=PA290&lpg=PA290&dq=%22Ess%C3%A9en%20concentration%22%20inequality&source=bl&ots=Eu394UqRdg&sig=HH6V6oICpE7JrWIDBuViYI_iJek&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=pTwuUsGZHoea1AXEqoGQDg&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22Ess%C3%A9en%20concentration%22%20inequality&f=false)).

The proof relies on a scaling argument and the identity 
$$\int_{\xi\in\mathbb R^d,|x|\lt\sqrt d}\exp(2i\pi\xi\cdot X)w(\xi)\mathrm d\xi=\Omega(1)^d\chi_{\{|X|\leqslant c\sqrt d\}},$$
where $w(\xi)=h* h(\xi)$, and $h(\xi)=\chi_{\{|\xi|\lt\sqrt{d/2}\}}e^{-C|\xi|^2}$.

Comment: May I ask about what $\Omega(1)^d$ means here? Many thanks!